# Should functions return pointer to derived or base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

When a function needs to return an object. Should it return it through a pointer to derived or base?

```
class B{

}

class D:public B{

}

// way 1: return pointer to derived
D* createDerived(){
    D* d = new D();
    return d;
}

// way 2: return pointer to base
B* createDerived(){
    B* d = new D();
    return d;
}
```

I have heard of "program to an interface not an implementation" which would suggest that we should return a pointer to base. However my intuition says it is better in this case to return a pointer to derived, because if the client code uses base pointers, this function would still work! On the other hand, if we return pointer to base and the client code uses derived pointers, this would not work for them. It seems that by returning a more "specific" pointer, we are allowing more flexibility for client code.

Another way to look at it is from the perspective of "program by contract." One of the suggestions is to promise as little as you can. By promising that we will return a very specific object, we follow this rule. However if we return a base pointer, it seems to me that we are promising a lot more.

Which is better design? Is my reasoning above correct?

I have a lot to learn on how to make modular, maintainable, extensible software, so please excuse if my reasoning/conclusion is nooby. I am very interested in learning. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: `Should functions return pointer` No, in most cases not.

Comment: I would expect a function named `createDerived()` to return what it actually created - a pointer to a `D` ("*You create a `D`, so give me a `D*`*"). Now, if you were to implement a class factory instead, where maybe `createDerived()` is the registered function for creating `D` objects, then it would have to return a base class pointer instead to satisfy the factory contract.

Comment: @deviantfan Hi deviantfan. Thank you for your comment. I know dealing with raw pointers is generally not good, but I did not want to complicate my question by involving smart pointers. The type of pointer is not relevant to my question. I simply want to know is it better to promise to return a base or a derived when you are returning a derived object. I wanted to keep my question/code as simple as possible :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi Remy, thank you for the reassurance! I completely agree with your reasoning. I thought maybe my intuition was misguiding me however it seems good so far!

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Why would it have to return a base pointer? With raw pointers, you could use covariant return types.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Maybe I am wrong, but I don't think covariance works when you have a class factory that uses a list of registered function pointers to create objects. All of the functions need to have the same signature in order to be stored in the list, and thus they need to have the same return type - a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Personally, I'd say the answer depends on the situation.  If the function is intended to match other functions that return base pointers, then it should as well.  If it's intended to be used in contexts where the derived class is required, then it should return a derived pointer to reflect that.  And so on.  Just my two cents.

Comment: Voted to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Right, I was thinking of "classical" OOP factory classes.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to answer this question in a general way. In particular, returning the more derived object **imposes additional restrictions on future implementations of the method**, while returning the base class **imposes more restrictions on the caller**. Which is best depends on the design of the application or library, and in particular the scope of functionality offered by `B` and `D` and the overall design of the API.

In general, you want to return the most-derived, or, loosely speaking, the most functional class, which doesn't constrain your future implementation choices. This allows your clients to use the return value efficiently, while still allowing you to the change the implementation in the future.

The primary downside of using the derived class `D` is that you expose more details to the client, which may be difficult or impossible to reverse later.

For example, imagine that that you have a method `reverse(std::ReversibleContainer &cont)`, which takes a container and returns a reversed *snapshot* of it (i.e., changes to the underlying container don't effect the returned snapshot).

In your initial implementation, you might decide to implement this as:

```
template<class BidirectionalIterator>
std::list<T> reverse(BidirectionalIterator &start, BidirectionalIterator &end) {
  std::vector output;
  std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), back_inserter(output))
  return output;
}
```

Later on, you might realize that you can avoid the copy of the underlying data for certain cases where the container (and elements) are constant, for example:

```
ImmutableIterator reverse(ImmutableBiderectionalIterator &input) {
  return ReversingImmutableBiderectionalIterator(input);
}
```

This container can use the knowledge that the input container is read-only to return a *view* of the input container, avoiding the copy, which simply remaps each access to result in the same semantics as a reversed container.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great answer! So there is a trade off between who gets flexibility, the function or the function's clients. Could you please try to explain your "reverse" example a bit more or perhaps use a different example? They both have the same return types...I don't get how that relates to returning different return types. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, the second example should have returned an ImmutableReversibleContainer, which makes it clear the implementation couldn't easily be changed.

Comment: To be clear, the update to use a IRC would only work in cases where an IRC was _co-variant_ with std::list - and in general it wouldn't be.

That's the crux of the example though - by offering `std::list` as the return type, you are forever constraining the implementation of the method.

The general rule is accept the minimal class required for arguments (e.g., accept Collection or iterator, rather than `list` or `vector`), and yet return the most specific class possible as a return value (since clients may get use out of the methods or performance characteristics offered by such methods).

Comment: Finally, the latter advice to return the most specific class must be balanced against implementation convenience, both current and future, as well as API considerations. If the method will never change in the future, you can offer a lot. If it's a library function that will live for a while, potentially with modifications, more thought is required.

Comment: So by returning a more specific class (std::list<T>) you limit the functions own implementation flexibility. This is evident when you decide that you want the function to return something different, however you can't, because your client may already be depending on that specific class that you returned. Is that the message of your example?

Comment: BeeOnRope, thank you so much for your explanation and advice! That makes perfect sense. So in summary. When taking in parameters, take the most general. When returning, return the most specific if you don't think the implementation of your function will change much. If you do think the implementation of your function will change, think twice about returning something too specific. Thanks again, I will give maybe one more day for additional answers (to hear from a few more people) before accepting your terrific answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I had to catch up on C++ to give a better example and I've modified the above. The core problem is when you've returned a _too general_ return type, which may be be easy to implement in your original method, but may be very difficult later. The idea of immutable views vs full copies is only the simplest example I could think of this type of issue, but it is pervasive.

Comment: Regarding "When taking in parameters, take the most general. When returning, return the most specific if you don't think the implementation of your function will change much". Exactly. It's a tradeoff when it comes to return types. Choosing a too-specific type will make optimizations and alternate implementations difficult. Too generic and your methods will not be useful to the callers. Sometimes you may need to add new types for the callers to use as parameters so you can, in turn, return a more useful type. That's the origin behind a lot of existing iterator-related types in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rename member functions to createB and createD and in second case return pointer to derived class, because you always can cast derived class pointer to base class, when reverse cast may fail.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer imo is *neither*. There is usually no need to return raw pointers from functions in your own code (exceptions below).

Instead, just return the created object itself:

```
class B { virtual ~B(){} };
class D : public B {};

// this function would make real sense only if D were a class template
auto createD()
{
    return D{};
}
```

This suffices in about any cases. Moreover, and importantly, it expresses what you get, namely an object of type `D` which you can use as required. Instead, when you get a raw pointer, it's from the first (i.e. without guessing the behaviour from the function name, reading the documentation, etc.) unclear what you're allowed to do with this raw pointer. Can you wrap it inside a `unique_ptr`? Are you allowed to delete it? Unclear. Returning an object (or better, a *well-designed* object, which basically means consistent RAII) releases you from having to answer those question -- just do what you want with the object.

Further, if you really need the pointer (which is an abstraction from the object), you can still wrap the return inside a suitable smart pointer like

```
auto d_uptr = std::make_unique<D>(createDerived());
auto d_sptr = std::make_shared<D>(createDerived());
```

or, similarly, also into smart base class pointers,

```
std::unique_ptr<B> = std::make_unique<D>(createDerived());
std::shared_ptr<B> b_sptr = std::make_shared<D>(createDerived());
```

This uses copy elision to construct the pointees and produces no overhead as compared to your function returning a `D*`. Note that as a rule the pointer should be a smart pointer, because only then you are freed directly from the obligation of having to delete it correctly somewhere later in the code.

One exception where you need raw pointers as function return types is the *clone pattern*, which applies when you want to copy an object via a base class pointer. Here one should use smart pointers as well as the function invoked by the user, but inside the class one has to use raw pointers in order to allow for covariant return types of virtual functions:

```
class B
{
    virtual ~B(){}
    auto clone() const
    {
         return std::unique_ptr<B>(clone_impl());
    }
protected:
    virtual B* clone_impl() const = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
protected:
    virtual D* clone_impl() const { return new D{*this}; };
};
```

There might be a lot of other exceptions (e.g. always when covariance is used) which I don't have in mind at the moment. But those are not *that* important imo.

Summarizing: don't use raw pointers as function return types unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the answer, but the type of pointer (smart or raw) used was not what I was wondering about. I simply want to know: if a function is returning a derived object, should it return it via a "pointer" (raw, smart, doesn't matter) to base or "pointer" to derived? My question is related to the principle "program to an interface not an implementation".

Comment: If you really have to return pointers -- of course the derived class pointer (I thought this was also implied by the discussion above). Otherwise you lose information. An upcast to the base class is fast and easy, a downcast from base to derived is error prone and expensive.

Comment: @MeLikeyCode: and again, it doesn't matter whether you "program to an interface" or not, the discussion above applies anyways. Don't return raw pointers from functions (exceptions above) and return smart pointers only with a good reason. Instead, return objects.

Comment: Great point about losing information. I still don't get you why returning an "object" would solve this problem at all? An object that uses RAII is also just like a (smart) pointer itself (or handle, w.e. you wanna call it)...so it doesn't really solve THIS particular issue, does it? I may not be understanding something here...

Comment: @MeLikeyCode: granted, a smart pointer -- usually a `unique_ptr` -- would do the job as good as an object. But it's an abstraction. That means, my advice is more based on principles. Just go on and return a smart pointer if you feel like it -- but not a raw pointer, because then the crucial information about ownership has to be deduced from somewhere else (the function name, the documentation, etc). But that's only advices, of course you can code as you like ;-)